# Can R select the specific folder during gs_upload processing?

Tags: r, google-sheets

When I use `gs_upload` in **googlesheets** package, the **.csv** file will upload into my root direction in google drive. Can I upload my .csv files into specific folder in google drive?
Below are my sampling code, any help will be thanksful.

```
write.csv(iris, "c:\\iris.csv", row.names=F)
gs_upload("c:\\iris.csv", "test_of_upload")
```

Comment: You can use the standard Google drive to do that.  Go to the  folder you want the files to end up in and select new and choose file upload.  Plus you can select more than one file. It's already build and ready to use.

Comment: @swchen I have exactly the same problem, have you solved this ?

Comment: @Kumpelka No I didn't solve this, maybe change it manually is the solution.